# Как адаптировать блок по высоте?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь скопировать вёрстку диалогового окна с [вот этого чата](https://chatra.io). Сам чат имеет фиксированную высоту. Внутри чат разбит на 3 блока. 1 блок имеет фиксированную высоту и прижат к верху. 3 блок имеет фиксированную высоту и прижать к низу. 2 блок занимает всё оставшееся пространство с возможностью прокрутки контента внутри себя. Главная проблема в том, что я не понимаю как адаптировать блок чата по высоте. То есть, чтобы основной блок чата уменьшался вместе с окном браузера. Есть идеи?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**html**

```
<div class="cart">
    <div class="cart-header">
        <p>Прижать к верху.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-body">
        <p>Занять все свободное место с возможностью прокрутки (overflow).</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-footer">
        <p>Прижать к низу.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.cart {
    position: fixed;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;

    // 576 px и больше.
    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
        right: 30px;
        bottom: 30px;
    }

    &.show {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        // 576 px и больше.
        @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
            max-width: 380px;
            max-height: 600px;
        }
    }
}

.cart-body {
    display: none;

    .cart.show > & {
        display: block;
    }
}

.cart-footer {
    display: none;

    .cart.show > & {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто. Для родительского блока `.chat_contanier` необходимо установить полную высоту окна браузера, т.е. 100%. Единица измерения `vh`. Точно также как и для его дочернего блока `chat`. Кроме этого, не забываем также установить и максимальную высоту для окна вашего чата `max-height`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.chat_contanier {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 450px;
}

.chat {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 450px;
}

.chat_top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.chat_bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.chat_center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 60px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat_contanier">
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="chat_top">Поддержка Чатры
    </div>
    <div class="chat_center">Диалог
    </div>
    <div class="chat_bottom">Сообщение...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю насколько это может тебе помочь, но если блоку дать

```
overflow: auto;
```

То он тянется ровно настолько, сколько ему надо.

Comment: Причём здесь это? Оно отвечает будет у элемента полоса прокрутки или нет

Answer (score 0):

Идея использовать единицу измерения `vh`.

В этом примере всё окно чата будет в высоту 30% от высоты экрана

```css
.cart {
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 15px;
  height: 30vh;
  min-height: 150px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cart-header {
  height: 50px;
}

.cart-body {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.cart-footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart">
  <div class="cart-header">
    <p>Прижать к верху.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-body">
    <p>Занять все свободное место с возможностью прокрутки (overflow).</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-footer">
    <p>Прижать к низу.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Или. В этом примере "тело" чата будет в высоту 30% от высоты экрана, а весь чат будет 30% + 100рх верхней и нижней части.

```css
.cart {
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 15px;
}

.cart-header {
  height: 50px;
}

.cart-body {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  height: 30vh;
}

.cart-footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart">
  <div class="cart-header">
    <p>Прижать к верху.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-body">
    <p>Занять все свободное место с возможностью прокрутки (overflow).</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-footer">
    <p>Прижать к низу.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```